# Rails Ransack gem: search for multiple values with one condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ransack

I use ransack gem and I have a select field `event_id` which can be either a string or an array, eg: 90 or [ 145, 147, 148 ]

The code I have, returns an error when an array is passed in:

```rb
ransack("job_name_cont" => job_name, "event_id_eq" => event_id).result
```

```rb
[1] pry(Job)> ransack("job_name_cont" => job_name, "event_id_eq" => event_ids).result 
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_i' for [145, 147, 148]:Array
Did you mean?  to_s
               to_a
               to_h
```

My model:

```rb
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs, dependent: :destroy
end
```

How can i search with event_id is array?

Comment: Does `ransack("job_name_cont" => job_name, "event_id_in" => [event_ids].flatten).result` work?

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working with event_id which must be an array

Comment: I will add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look over [Ransack's Search Matchers](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#search-matchers) you will see one with `*_in - match any values in array`, which is what you need if you want to search in arrays.

Because your `event_ids` can come in either as a string or an array and `*_in` requires and array, we have to make sure we always feed it an array.

```
[event_ids].flatten # returns an array all the time
```

The query below should works properly now.

```
ransack("job_name_cont" => job_name, "event_id_in" => [event_ids].flatten).result
```